# Algorithm for generating blocks that count correct sequence of moves in block escape puzzle

Tags: phaserjs

I'm trying to create a block escape puzzle game in phaser 3. What I'm planning to do is to generate and position the dynamic block and mainblock. Factor dynamic block number of correct sequence of moves to free the main block. For example I need to generate mainblock and dynamic blocks that will take 4 correct sequence of move to free the main block. What algorithm should I use or any tips to achieve this? Here's the video link of the game https://www.youtube.com/shorts/DwZ1UUwfikM

Comment: honestly to generate puzzels doesn't sound like a good idea, because apart from the work of creating a working algorithem, you will never know how hard/good they will be. Best solution would be to create a "puzzel-editor" and just craft them ( 50 - 100 ). _(or better let the players access to the editor, so that they can create and submit them)_  this would make the game better.  OR just write a programm that tries out each possible move, BUT than you should limit the max/min moves (and prevent moving stones twice in a row), since if not this could take a "while". ;-)